# How do I scrap the text of anchor tag using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```html
   <span class="companyName">
<a data-tn-element="companyName" class="turnstileLink companyOverviewLink" target="_blank" href="/cmp/Lush-Cosmetics" rel="noopener">LUSH Cosmetics</a>
</span>
```

I did this -
item.find('span', class_ ='companyName').find('a').text

But it gives me the error -
item.find('span', class_ ='companyName').find('a').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Clearly there's _some_ such span that doesn't have a link, and that's why your code is failing. It's not failing for that HTML, though.

Comment: Question needs some more details - Code works fine for given HTML, so take a closer look into your `soup` if this element exists there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
item.find('span',{'class':'companyName'}).find('a').text
```

Working code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = '''
<div class="job_seen_beacon">
<span class="companyName">
<a data-tn-element="companyName" class="turnstileLink companyOverviewLink" target="_blank" href="/cmp/Lush-Cosmetics" rel="noopener">LUSH Cosmetics</a>
</span></div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,features="lxml")
anchorText = soup.find('span',{'class':'companyName'}).find('a').text
print(anchorText)
```

Comment: No, just checked. It gives the following error -  company = item.find('span',{'class':'companyName'}).find('a').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: what have you stored in `item`?

Comment: divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'job_seen_beacon')
    for item in divs:

Comment: can you paste the html for that div as well?

Comment: divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'job_seen_beacon')
    for item in divs:
        title = item.find('h2', class_ ='jobTitle').find('span').text.strip()
        company = item.find('span',{'class':'companyName'}).find('a').text
        try:
            salary = item.find('div', class_ = 'salary-snippet').find('span').text.strip()

Comment: except:
            salary = ''
        summary = item.find('div', {'class' : 'job-snippet'}).text.strip().replace('\n', '')

        job = {
            'title': title,
            'company': company,
            'salary': salary,
            'summary': summary
        }
        joblist.append(job)
    return

Comment: I needed to see HTML, having said that, I have updated with a working copy of the code with a mockup HTML